# How to send and/or show multiple images from one large image

Tags: javascript, image

I have a single page image and I want to show selected areas of the page in various locations of my html page without making multiple calls to the server for each view. The page image is dynamic so I assume that I cannot use CSS - or can I? I can select and bundle the images on the server.

Comment: Can you set up an example? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand why a dynamic image should contain multiple images...

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds exactly like a CSS sprite, and there's no reason that you can't use it on a "dynamic" page. The image will be cached by the browser and only downloaded once.

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites